# CAS redirect to URL on succesfull login

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220454/in-cas-how-can-i-restrict-access-to-only-one-service-if-agreement-is-not-yet-acc) a solution is described to handle redirects to a custom URL based on a condition via use of `AccessStrategy`.

This however is part of the unauthorized login logical flow therefore results into a still not-logged in user arriving at the end url we redirect to. (via `getUnauthorizedUrl`)

If we want to redirect the user based on a condition, say via injecting an action to the webflow, how can we manipulate the return URL to be changed into a custom one?

`WebUtils.getService(requestContext)` include getters of the source/originalUrl but no obvious way to set/manipulate said value through an action bean.

p.s. Currently using CAS version 5.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses for *normal* web applications from CAS are built using `WebApplicationServiceResponseBuilder`.

If you examine [this block](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/5.3.x/core/cas-server-core-services/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/config/CasCoreServicesConfiguration.java#L94) you will find that the final response is built using `WebApplicationServiceResponseBuilder` bean. It is only created conditionally, if an existing bean is not already found in the context by the same name. So to provide your own, you just need to register a bean with the same name using your own `@Configuration` class.

```java
@Bean
public ResponseBuilder<WebApplicationService> webApplicationServiceResponseBuilder() {
    return new MyOwnWebApplicationServiceResponseBuilder(...);
}
```

...and then proceed to design your own `MyOwnWebApplicationServiceResponseBuilder`, perhaps even by extending `WebApplicationServiceResponseBuilder` and overriding what you need where necessary to build the final redirect logic conditionally.

To learn about how `@Configuration` classes work in general, you can:

- [Review this post](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Management-Extensions.html)
- or [this post](https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/21/cas-autocfg-strategy/)
- or consult the documentation for Spring and/or Spring Boot.